# Window function get first and last row from each group

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto, amazon-athena, trino

I am using window function on presto to get the first and last row of each group. I did apply the `ROW_NUMBER()` on my **Name** column for Partition with **Percent** column sort and I get below result

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT Name, Price, Percent, Volume, time, date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Percent DESC) AS rn
FROM TABLE_NAME  ORDER BY Name asc
```

**Current Output:**

```
Name    Price   Percent  Volume              time          date    rn
AABB    0.015   42.55   25980719    2020-12-29 10:23:11 2020-12-29  1
AABB    0.014   33.33   22640655    2020-12-29 10:20:42 2020-12-29  2
AABB    0.014   33.33   22640655    2020-12-29 10:21:11 2020-12-29  3
AABB    0.0137  30.0    21466099    2020-12-29 10:19:20 2020-12-29  4
AABB    0.0135  28.57   20461208    2020-12-29 10:17:19 2020-12-29  5
AABB    0.013   23.81   20201208    2020-12-29 10:16:41 2020-12-29  6
AABB    0.013   23.81   19129182    2020-12-29 10:15:20 2020-12-29  7
AABB    0.0125  19.05   14513969    2020-12-29 10:07:15 2020-12-29  8
AABB    0.0125  19.05   15580088    2020-12-29 10:09:14 2020-12-29  9
AABB    0.012   14.29   14313969    2020-12-29 10:06:44 2020-12-29  10
AABB    0.012   14.29   12924448    2020-12-29 10:15:14 2020-12-29  11
ABQQ    0.025   74.83   6809380     2020-12-29 09:50:04 2020-12-29  1
ABQQ    0.024   67.83   4196759     2020-12-29 09:48:10 2020-12-29  2
ABQQ    0.0225  57.34   935554      2020-12-29 09:06:13 2020-12-29  3
ABQQ    0.0143  -5.61   1600927     2020-12-29 09:43:51 2020-12-29  4
ABQQ    0.0143  -5.61   1600927     2020-12-29 09:41:51 2020-12-29  5
ABQQ    0.0143  -5.61   1600927     2020-12-29 09:36:52 2020-12-29  6
```

**Expected Output 1:** (Sort by **Percent** and select only **highest+lowest Percent** value row)

```
Name    Price   Percent  Volume              time          date    rn
AABB    0.015   42.55   25980719    2020-12-29 10:23:11 2020-12-29  1
AABB    0.012   14.29   12924448    2020-12-29 10:15:14 2020-12-29  11
ABQQ    0.025   74.83   6809380     2020-12-29 09:50:04 2020-12-29  1
ABQQ    0.0143  -5.61   1600927     2020-12-29 09:36:52 2020-12-29  6
```

**Expected Output 2:** (Sort by **time** and select only **highest+lowest time** value row)

```
Name    Price   Percent  Volume              time          date    rn
AABB    0.015   42.55   25980719    2020-12-29 10:23:11 2020-12-29  1
AABB    0.012   14.29   14313969    2020-12-29 10:06:44 2020-12-29  10
ABQQ    0.025   74.83   6809380     2020-12-29 09:50:04 2020-12-29  1
ABQQ    0.0225  57.34   935554      2020-12-29 09:06:13 2020-12-29  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a subquery:

```
SELECT Name, Price, Percent, Volume, time, date,
FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Percent) AS seqnum_asc,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Percent DESC) AS seqnum_desc
      FROM TABLE_NAME t
     ) t
WHERE 1 IN (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
ORDER BY Name asc;
```

If you want `time` as a separate query, just adjust the `ORDER BY` in the windowing clause.  If you want all in one query, then add two new "seqnum"s based on `time`.